# How to get the username in django admin.py file

Tags: django

I trying to get the username in django admin.py file. I am working on a project purely modification of admin site. I dont have view.py and form.py file in it. I am trying to print the username in the shell so that I can do the necessary action based upon the user group type.

Like,

```
user = User.objects.get(username="demostaff")
print('is_staff', user.is_staff)
print('is_superuser', user.is_superuser)
```

Could you please suggest how to get the username object.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I used in my project.

```
class panel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        print(request.user)
```